# Not able to reset the root user password on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7

I installed Centos7 recently on a laptop.  Somehow in the past day the administrator account is no longer administrator (can't sudo).

Tried fixing this by seeing if the root password could be reset and then use root to fix the user account.

On the Centos7 website it refers to the RHEL7 documentation to add `init=/bin/sh` to the grub boot parameters (the link below), but it gives me a message mentioning it cannot find the file `/bin/sh`.   I also tried `/bin/bash`, same file not found message.

```
access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Terminal_Menu_Editing_During_Boot.html#sec-Recovering_Root_Password
```

How can I grant the main login administrator privileges again?

Comment: In my opinion, this question should be sent to "Server Fault" or "Super User" webs instead of "StackOverflow"... Nevertheless, if Centos server has not been configured to require the superuser password in single user runlevel, I suggest to boot in single user mode and change the root password.

Answer (score 1):

**Resetting your forgot root user password**

If your system is running then first you have to `turn it off`. And after turning it off, follow the below steps.

**Step 1:** `Turn on` your computer.

**Step 2:** When you see the `GRUB2 boot menu`, it means boot option, then press letter `e` to edit the boot menu.

**Step 3:** You have to look for the line which is starting with `linux16`.

**Step 4:** At the end of this line, you have to type `rd.break` and then press `Ctrl + x`

**Step 5:** You will see the screen which will start `switch_root:/#`
Then, you can start typing below commands in a series

`mount -o remount,rw /sysroot`

`chroot /sysroot`

Now to reset the password use the below command.

`passwd root`

Type **new password for root**

**retype the password**

Type the below command to relabel the SELinux context

`touch /.autorelabel`

And now type exit twice.

`exit`

`exit`

and wait, it will automatically reboot the machine. that’s it. If you find any difficulty then you can write a message.

You can also visit my blog post. The blog post URL, you can find below.

[Reset your forgot root user password in Linux in 3 minutes](https://www.linuxgurus.in/reset-forgot-root-password/)

Comment: the link which I have shared is working fine.

Comment: can you check -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9HO2.png

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the rescue mode grub entry at boot instead of the default centos entry and adding the "init=/bin/sh" to the parameter list did work... I was able to get the commandline as root and follow the recovery steps in the linked document above to change password, update the /etc/sudoers file.

Answer (score 0):

There are small changes on resetting the root password in CentOS7. Google shows lot of useful links. One of which is below :
[Reset the root password in CentOS7](http://tweaktheserver.com/reset-the-password-from-single-user-mode-in-centos7/)